# Python and NGREP

Tags: python, process, input, system, ngrep

I want to be able to start and stop an NGREP process from inside my python code. I really dont have experience with python on a system level.

Normally I run NGREP from the command line, but I would like to be able to run it from a script every hour and capture the trace and then process the results.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to achieve this.

By the way, I really just need to be able to do a packet capture, perhaps Python has builtin capabilities for this, maybe tcpdump?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert but I would do this:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import re
import time

keep_running = 1 #Loop flag
wait_hours = 12  #Stop for 12 hours and then run again
run_hours = 1    #We will run ngrep for an hour. The nth run will be dumped to net_log_n.txt
f_num=0
hours_so_far=0
run_time_limit = 100    #Suppose you only want to take a log for 100 hours while you are away.
while keep_running:
    ngrep_cmd = "sudo ngrep -ixW >  net_log_" + str(fnum) + ".txt &"
    subprocess.call([ngrep_cmd], shell=True)
    time.sleep(run_hours*3600)
    subprocess.call(["sudo killall ngrep"], shell=True)
    time.sleep(wait_hours*3600)
    f_num += 1
    hours_so_far += run_hours
    if hours_so_far >= run_time_limit:
        keep_running = 0
```

You will have to run it as root or with sudo.

I hope it helps!

Comment: No need to define `keep_running` if you never change it, just use `while True:`. Your `os.system(sudo killall ngrep)` line is missing quotes, and you should *really* be using `subprocess.call` instead.

Comment: Hello Martijn, sorry I was clumsy with the syntax and thanks for correcting! I put 'keep_running' there to give the idea of an optional line 'if run_hours > 100: keep_running=0', to Dave. I am on a Mac Os 10.4.11 and I have Python 2.3.5, so I do not think I have access to subprocess module.

Comment: I wish I could get 2.6 at least. :)

Comment: No need to pass in a list if you set `shell=True`, and in the second `subprocess.call`, there is no need to use `shell=True` since you are not redirecting the output.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) and [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect). If you don't want to install pexpect, you can use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead.

EDIT: In response to the comment:

```
import os
from signal import SIGTERM, SIGKILL
os.kill(pid, SIGTERM) #you can also send SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM. 
#You might also have to put this call in a try block and catch OSError
#Only available on *NIX
```

EDIT2: If you want to hand-roll the packet capture, use [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/). This should almost certainly do what you want, since tcpdump uses libpcap itself.

Comment: I'm not sure why a threading.Timer would be useful in this case.

Comment: Because he wants to run it every hour... So, create a `threading.Timer(3600, runNgrep, args, kwargs)` to run the program and create another `threading.Timer` when the program finishes... Where `runNgrep` is a function taking `args` and `kwargs` as arguments, obviously.

Comment: These are good suggestions. Any idea how to kill the process though? I see the docs. it seems like send_signal(), terminate() and exit() methods are only available in python 2.6 I am running python 2.5. Following your suggestion, I use subprocess.Popen then get the process id and then run subprocess.Popen with a kill pid to ed the process. Not so elegant, perhaps there is a better way to terminate the process?

Answer (score 0):

its not in-built, but you can try [Packet Capture and Injection Library](http://pycap.sourceforge.net/)